# Is there a way to store the exponent of my vector values as a variable in itself?

Tags: matlab

```
testVector =

   1.0e+10 *

    3.5688    3.1110    5.2349
```

Is it possible to take out the exponent (not sure what it's called) of a vector and store it as a variable? E.g. in this case the variable would have value `1.0e+10`

Comment: @marsei Yes it is. I should have looked first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the value of the exponent using `log10`:

```
testVector = [3.5688e+10   3.1110e+10   5.2349e+10];
lowExp = min(floor(log10(testVector)));
eVal = 10^lowExp;
```

Result:

```
eVal =    1.0000e+10
```

Then you'll need to divide your original vector by `eVal`:

```
newTestV = testVector/eVal

newTestV =

   3.5688   3.1110   5.2349
```